# Where do I download Microsoft Word 16.64 updater?

Tags: macos, ms-office

I have the perpetual license for Office 365 for Mac.

I have just word installed.

Today the autoupdater showed the message that version 16.64 is available for update. I have 16.63.1.

Obviously Autoupdater failed to update with the message "The update could not be updated at this time, try again later", what is typical.

The last time it happened I downloaded the updater package and installed manually but I don't seem to find 16.64 updater for word on the web.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft maintains a direct download index web site. It’s geared for professional Macintosh administration staff, but anyone can make use of it.

- https://macadmins.software/

Here is the word update you need - https://officecdnmac.microsoft.com/pr/C1297A47-86C4-4C1F-97FA-950631F94777/MacAutoupdate/Microsoft_Word_16.64.22081401_Updater.pkg